# Do I format other works' titles in my title?

Tags: style, mla

I'm currently writing an essay in MLA format about a short story, and would like to include the title of the short story in my title. We all know that titles of short stories are underlined when hand-written and italicized when typed, but...

Should I apply proper formatting to another work's title when it appears in my title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MLA style guide recommends the following when it comes to [referencing other works in your title](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/01/):

> Use quotation marks and/or italics when referring to other works in
>   your title, just as you would in your text: *Fear and Loathing in Las*
>   *Vegas* as Morality Play; Human Weariness in "After Apple Picking"